# How can I register a simple callback function and pass arguments to that function?

Tags: c, callback, function-pointers

What I would like to do is :

- a simple function "register_function" allowing a user to indicate a callback function to call (that this user has implemented)
- when calling that function with "call_callback", to be able to pass arguments like a buffer for example

Here is my code:

```
static void (*callback)(int *buffer, int size) = NULL;

void register_callback(void (*ptr)())
{
    (*callback) = ptr;
}

void call_callback(int *buffer, int size)
{
    (*callback)(buffer, size);
}
```

The problem is that I have a compile-time error in the register_callback declaration.

Comment: Any error in particular?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `register_callback()` the assignment is just:

```
void register_callback(void (*ptr)( int *buffer, int size ))
{
    callback = ptr;
}
```

Please note that I also added the parameter declarations to the definition of `ptr` so the compiler can check for the correct function pointer type passed (assuming you have an identical prototype)